# Cordova Geolocation : app startup with GPS disabled

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, gps, geolocation

Cordova Geolocation works really well when GPS is enabled.  If the app is launched with GPS enabled, then GPS is disabled, and then re-enabled... everything works as expected.  If, however, I start with GPS **disabled**, there is absolutely nothing to be done but to restart with GPS enabled.  Enabling GPS while the app is running has no effect, and there appears to be no way to retrieve the position.  I've tried with both pure Cordova and mdg:geolocation Meteor package... same result.

Tested on Android

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to ask if your gps is enable before and then try to enable it automatically or ask the user to change the Location Settings?

I had recommended a Plugin to do this here:

[Cordova Angularjs ask for GPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35165351/cordova-angularjs-ask-for-gps)